# Can't install Powershell 3.0

Tags: installer, powershell-3.0

Im trying to install powershell 3.0 on my Win7 64 bit pc, but I get the error "the update is not applicable to your computer."

After googling the error, all the solutions I see are that you need to install .net 4 full profile.

However, .net 4 won't install, as I have .net 4.5 installed.  I did a repair on .net 4.5 to see if that would help, but it didnt.

Anyone know of a solution?  Im wondering if I have to uninstall .net 4.5 and 4 and reinstall them.

Update:  I uninstalled .NET 4.5 and 4 and reinstalled the 4.0 full profile - no luck
I double checked I had the correct version for Win 7 64 bit - I do...

Comment: How can we help you if you don't provide the installation error codes?

Comment: there are no error codes, as there are no errors other than "the update is not applicable."

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place replacement for .NET Framework.  **So having .NET Framework 4.5 is NOT the reason this installer is failing.**  Are you saying that the installer doesn't even start AT ALL?

Comment: what part do you not understand?  The Powershell 3 installer exits with "the update is not applicable"  .Net4.5 is installed and is working fine.

Comment: You have Windows 7 Service Pack 1 installed correct?  Just verify you meet all the requirements listed here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595 with the understanding that `.NET Framework 4.5` is an replacement for `.NET Framework 4.0`

Comment: The logical solution would be to get rid of `.NET Framework 4.5` replace it with `.NET Framework 4.0` then see if `Powershell 3.0` would install.  At that point you could install `.NET Framework 4.5` and verify thats indeed the reason the installer wasn't working.  I don't meant to sound short by when I am able to find tons of information on how to solve this problem, it makes it look like, you didn't research the problem before you asked for help.  You should read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847769.aspx

Comment: I read those, they werent helpful, thats why I asked here.  I suppose I can try uninstalling the .NETs and reinstall them.

Comment: If you don't answer my important questions I can't help.

Comment: @Keltari: Managed to get it to install? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: It's a shame that something like this should be such a brittle process. It's 2016 and I'm still facing this same issue upgrading powershell. Unfortunately your list detailing what eventually worked for you is a journey round the world. I'm demoralized even before starting!

Comment: I am seeing exactly the same error message on Windows 10, I've tried 3-4 different powershells now all of them fail to install. The error message doesn't give any hint whatsoever about why it failed. Just "Not applicable". Also many of the people commenting here should be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got Powershell 3 to install!  This was a complete PITA.

To be honest, Ive tried so many things and got so many errors, Im not entirely sure what did the trick exactly.  I dont know if all the steps were necessary, but in the end it ended up working.

- Uninstalled .NET 4.5
- Uninstalled .NET 4
- Uninstalled any other .NET
  related applications such as SDKs and some other things
- rebooted
- Installed .NET 4 Full client profile for Win 7 64 bit
- Installed
  patches to .NET 4
- rebooted
- extracted the .CAB files from the
  installer for Powershell 3 for Win 7 64 bit
- ran pkmgr on the
  extracted .CAB file (I dont think this helped, I know it failed in
  many attempts while trying to get it working)
- ran wusa.exe on the
  extracted .CAB file (I think this is what did it in the end) got a
  reboot notification
- rebooted
- ran a get-host in powershell and it
  returned version 3.  (woohoo!)
- reinstalled .NET 4.5
- installed patches
  for .NET 4.5 rebooted
- ran a get-host in powershell and it still
  worked returned version 3 (phew)

Comment: I don't feel safe uninstalling frameworks ;(

Answer (score 1):

Check you don't have a pre-release version installed. If so, uninstall it first then try again.

Alternatively, if you're absolutely sure you have all the pre-requisites in place, there is a possible workaround:

> Unpack the EXE as if it were a ZIP file (I used 7-zip), open CMD in the same
>   directory, then run the following substituting the name of your extracted CAB file:
>
> `start /w %SystemRoot%\system32\pkgmgr.exe /ip /m:Windows6.1-KB2506143-x86.cab`
>
> Wait until prompted to reboot, then reboot.

Source: [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/771892/v3-installation-says-the-update-is-not-applicable-to-your-computer-on-some-versions-of-windows-7) - Quote was posted as a workaround and has been edited slightly to improve grammar

Comment: I gave it a shot, seemed promising, but eventually errored out with "can not find specified file"  ]

Answer (score 1):

I have windows 7 home premium.  I had the same issue and found a solution that worked for me in a book I purchased.  The book is "Learn windows PowerShell 3 in a month of lunches".  (second edition)In Chapter 1, 1.5 it states that PowerShell 3 requires .NET Framework v4.  I downloaded it from Microsoft website and then I was able to download and install PowerShell 3 without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get this error it's because I accidentally downloaded the wrong version, since I'm on x64 also I d/l the x86 version or ia64 version by accident. Could that be the case? simplest things first I suppose :-)

**UPDATE Due To More Information**

Also, MS says .net 4.5 works fine, so no problem there http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx

Comment: double and triple checked I have the right version... I do.