# Troubles running Azure powershell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, azure

I'm trying to install Azure Powershell, following the instructions on [this page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/#Prereq).

The installation seems to run fine and proceeds without errors.

However, once it's finished, I can't manage to find the `Azure Powershell` application. I dispose of various terminals

- Windows Azure Command Prompt
- Windows Azure Storage Command line

But none of these seems to work. By work, I mean successfully run the first command in the example :

```
Add-AzureAccount
```

When I do, it gives me the following error :

```
'Add-Azure Account' is not recognized as an internal control 
or external, operable program or batch file.
```

On top of that, I see no mention of azure Powershell in my "All installed softwares" list :

[image]

I can run the following commands successfully :

```
Import-Module MSOnline
Get-Module MSOnline 
    gives me -> Manifest   MSOnline                  {Add-MsolRoleMember, Remove-MsolForeignGroupFromRole, Get-MsolFederation...
```

However, the following command gives all the same error (`ModuleNotFound`) :

```
Import-Module Azure
Import-Module AzureResourceManager
Import-Module AzureProfile
```

It's quite logical since they don't appear in my module list :

```
PS C:\Users\matthews> Get-Module -ListAvailable

ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Manifest   AppLocker                 {}
Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}
Manifest   MSOnline                  {}
Manifest   MSOnlineExtended          {}
Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {}
Manifest   PSReadline                {}
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack       {}
```

To conclude, the solution provided [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/568257/import-module-azure-fails) doesn't work, as there is no `PowerShell` directory in the `Windows Azure` folder.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is this a problem caused by the installation ?

NB : I also tried to install it using the standalone installer, but in this case, I get an explicit error message :

```
This setup requires the Windows PowerShell 3.0 or compatible version to be installed.
```

I'm having troubles installing the new Powershell version for various reasons, but it may be the solution.

Comment: Try adding -Command "Import-Module MSOnline" as a run argument for PowerShell.

Comment: @SamuelNicholson I'm now able to run this command, but I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: @fxm - Why don't you just install the [Powershell 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) and try using the standalone installer of Azure. Note: Windows 7 SP1 is required to install PS 3.0

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss Until now, I'm facing the problem described here : http://superuser.com/questions/541733/cant-install-powershell-3-0/545273 . The provided solution didn't work, so I'm still searching.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\..."
```

Can work but the path has changed in the time.

You probably just need to reboot, so the $env:PSModulePath will be updated.

BUT if you when a quick fix without the need to reboot you could run this script it will do the trick.

```
if( (Get-Module -ListAvailable azure | measure).Count -eq 0 )
{
    # == Refresh the Environment variable if just intall the tools without rebooting and try again
    $env:PSModulePath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath","Machine")

    if( (Get-Module -ListAvailable azure | measure).Count -eq 0 )
    {
        echo("You must install the Azure PowerShell Tools. Go at: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9811175&clcid=0x409")
        Read-Host "Press enter key to close"
        exit
    }
}

echo("Azure PowerShell is installed")
```

I hope this helps.