# Can't run start-process command

Tags: command-line, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run a command found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/545273/240094). The command is

```
start /w %SystemRoot%\system32\pkgmgr.exe /ip /m:Windows6.1-KB2506143-x86.cab
```

Trouble is, it doesn't work for me. Indeed, it returns the following error :

```
Start-Process : Impossible de trouver un paramètre positionnel acceptant l'argument « /ip ».
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 6
+ start <<<<  /w C:\Windows\System32\PkgMgr.exe /ip /m:Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.cab
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

As I'm a neophyte to powershell, I'm having troubles understanding the various options. `help start`  gives me a list of parameter, but I found no mention of `/w`, `/ip` or `/m`.

To sum up, I would like to

- be able to run the command
- understand what it does.

Comment: `/w`, `/ip` and `/m` are switches for `pkgmgr.exe`, not for start. Try putting double quotes around the command like this: `start /w "%SystemRoot%\system32\pkgmgr.exe /ip /m:Windows6.1-KB2506143-x86.cab"`

Comment: in fact, I don't see the reason why you even need `start /w`. It is only used when starting multiple programs from batch script to [force sequential execution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198044). You might as well omit `start /w`

Comment: @smc Good to know for the switches. I tried adding the quotes, but it gives me a `FileNotFound`. However, removing `start /w` makes the command run, so I guess that's all I wanted :) .

Comment: hm... not sure about `File not found`, but hey, as long as your problem is resolved, its all good. I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switches `/w`, `/ip` and `/m` relate to `pkgmgr.exe` rather then `start`. Here is a link to [MS website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749465(v=ws.10).aspx) were switches and options for `pkgmgr.exe` are described in the details

Try removing `start /w` from your command. It is only used in batch scripts to ensure [sequential execution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198044) of commands. You don't need it when running one singe command from the terminal.

Just do

> `%SystemRoot%\system32\pkgmgr.exe /ip /m:Windows6.1-KB2506143-x86.cab`

If you are interested in some extra info, read ["What is Package Manager?"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748979(v=ws.10).aspx). This should help you to understand what the command does. The essence is:

> Package Manager (Pkgmgr.exe) is a new Windows Vista command-line tool
>   that you can use offline to install, remove, or update Windows
>   packages.

`/ip` switch is used to install single package

`/m` is a compulsory switch after which you have to specifies the directory with the package manifest and payload.

Comment: You may want to add the details on the switches you mentionned in your first comment, it was useful to me and perhaps to someone else.